# Why do i get an Error whenever i try to set a PATH for Python? Tried Everything

Tags: python, python-3.x, path, environment-variables, pythonpath

I'm new to all of this so bear with me:

I desperately need help with setting a PATH for Python. I've looked up every possible explanation as to why I'm getting an error, and I've tried every supposed solution but nothing has worked. I'm on a Windows OS and I've tried changing the system variable path with the advanced settings and I've even tried to use the set command in the Command Prompt. Anything you can name I've tried it...unless that is someone can offer me good advice.

I always refresh the command prompt afterwards to test the PATH but it still doesn't work. I type in "python", or "Python35", etc; and I end up getting an error saying "(python or whatever I typed) is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file".

After two days of watching tutorial after tutorial and reading forum after forum, I'm getting a little frustrated and if someone could help me out here, that would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: When you `echo %PATH%` is the directory that contains your Python interpreter in there?

Comment: When you say that you've "refreshed the command prompt", have you tried logging out and logging back in and reopening it?

Comment: @kindall yes it has all of those directories and at the end its got ";C:\Python35.

Comment: @AaronD No, ill try that though

Comment: I believe you need to add ``C:\Python35\Bin`` to the ``%PATH``. The actual ``Python.exe`` is in a ``Bin/`` folder I believe.

Comment: Ok, so I've don't everything you guys have suggested. Still getting the error. If it helps i'll tell you the address that I have in the PATH in system variables. "C:\Python\Python35\bin". Also for some reason when I first tried to create a path, there was no path for Python in the system variable section, only in the user variable section. So I created one in the system variable section.

Comment: On my windows machine with 3.4 and 2.7 installed it has the Scripts subfolder - C:\Python34\;C:\Python34\Scripts;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts;